# Why am I getting this error : requires a return value or an exception to throw?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, rhino-mocks

I get the following error when I attempt to run my test. I've tried **`IgnoreArguments()`**  , but that does not seem to do the trick.  This exception is only thrown when I attempt **`mock.Ordered()`** if I do **`mock.Record()`** then it passes.

> System.InvalidOperationException : Previous method
>   'IProductRepository.GetAllProducts();' requires a return value or an
>   exception to throw.

---

```
 [Test]
        public void TestwithOrderedRecordsandPlayBack()
        {
            var mock = new MockRepository();
            var productRepository = mock.StrictMock<IProductRepository>();

            var product = new Grains
            {
                Name = "Wonder Bread",
                Category = "Grains"
            };

            IList list = new ArrayList();
            //Class under test
            var service = new ProductService(productRepository);

            using (mock.Ordered())
            {
                Expect.Call(productRepository
                    .GetAllProducts())
                    .IgnoreArguments()
                    .Return(new ArrayList());
                Expect.Call(()=>productRepository.SaveProduct(product));
            }

            using (mock.Playback())
            {
                list = service.GetAllProducts();
                service.SaveProduct(product);
            }
        }
```

---

Service call:

```
 public virtual IList GetAllProducts()
        {
            IList list = _productRepository.GetAllProducts();
            return list;
            //throw new System.Exception("Not implemented");
        }



public virtual IList GetAllProducts()
        {
            IList list = _productRepository.GetAllProducts();
            return list;
            //throw new System.Exception("Not implemented");
        }
```

Comment: Well what does your service call look like? Is it *really* such a thin layer that it just passes the requests down to your repository verbatim?

Comment: It's not about what you *could* just have - but what *does* your code have?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I place it in the edits above.

Comment: Well now you've shown *one* service call, but you're making two in your tests...

Comment: @JonSkeet, added the other service call now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        using (mock.Ordered())
        {
            Expect.Call(productRepository
                .GetAllProducts())
                .IgnoreArguments()
                .Return(new ArrayList());
            Expect.Call(() => productRepository.SaveProduct(product));
        }
```

This fails, on the exact same error you describe.
    System.InvalidOperationException : Previous method 'IProductRepository.GetAllProducts();' requires a return value or an exception to throw.

The reason for this is that the mock repository never left Record mode. You might think (I did too) that `mock.Ordered()` puts the repository in some kind of ordered record state, but it doesn't. So you need to specify when you are done recording behaviour.

You can do this in two ways:

```
        using (mock.Record())
        using (mock.Ordered())
        {
            Expect.Call(productRepository.GetAllProducts()).Return(new ArrayList());
            Expect.Call(() => productRepository.SaveProduct(product));
        }
```

Or drop mock.ReplayAll() when you are done recording:

```
        using (mock.Ordered())
        {
            Expect.Call(productRepository.GetAllProducts()).Return(new ArrayList());
            Expect.Call(() => productRepository.SaveProduct(product));
        }

        mock.ReplayAll();

        using (mock.Playback())
        {
            service.GetAllProducts();
            service.SaveProduct(product);
        }
```

I tested both, both work.

Comment: Thank you, let me know when you get more details.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but dropped it as answer so that you can easily read the answer/comment. **Let me know if this is not the solution, then I'll remove the answer to avoid confusion.**

I think your problem is in

`Expect.Call(()=>productRepository.SaveProduct(product))`

You are in record mode already (`mock.Ordered()`) so there is no need to specify `Expect.Call()`.

`Expect.Call()` demands a return value. You are just looking for a way to verify that the method save is being called.

I think you should change your code into:

```
        using (mock.Ordered())
        {
            Expect.Call(productRepository
                .GetAllProducts())
                .IgnoreArguments()
                .Return(new ArrayList());
            productRepository.SaveProduct(product);
        }
```

(You might think that you call SaveProduct in your test method, but you won't, RhinoMocks is smarter than that and will record this void call)

Comment: I tried your proposal above, Im still running into the same error. Leave this answer up though because it provides info about the workings or Ordered and Expect.

Comment: k hang on then i'll try to reproduce your error. need to fire up VS.